# Sheaf cohomology of a complement of finitely many points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a smooth, projective surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and $p \subset X$ a closed point in $X$. How do I compute $H^1(\mathcal{O}_{X\backslash p})$? 
Any reference/idea will be most welcome.

Comment: No. Why do you think this should hold?

Comment: @abx I have edited the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For what follows, I recommend SGA 2 ([available on Arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511279)). There is an exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\rightarrow H^1(X\smallsetminus p,\mathcal{O}_X)\rightarrow H^2_{p}(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\rightarrow H^2(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$$
where $ H^2_{p}(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is infinite-dimensional, while $H^i(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is finite-dimensional. Therefore $H^1(X\smallsetminus p,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is infinite-dimensional. The computation of  $ H^2_{p}(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$  given in SGA 2 and the exact sequence above give an expression for this space, probably not very pleasant.

Comment: Can you suggest some English references..